# Centralizando uma lista com flutuadores

Tags: css3

quando acho que estou pegando posicionamento me ocorre essas cascas de banana.
Quero centralizar essa lista `.example` em relação ao seu pai `.quadro`. A lista se trata de uma `ul` com `float:left`.

Por que não consigo centralizar esta lista `.example` em relação ao seu pai `.quadro` aplicando propriedades de margin? Aparentemente não consigo limpar flutuadores usando clearfix na própria lista, por isso crie a div `.test` e nela apliquei a técnica. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Aqui está o HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="quadro">
        <div class="test">
            <ul class="example">
                <li>Primeiro</li>
                <li>Segundo</li>
                <li>Terceiro</li>
                <li>Quarto</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

E aqui está o Css

```
    margin: 60px auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #FFBE4A;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test:before,
.test:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.test:after {
  clear: both;
}

.test{
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.test{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.example li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    background: rgb(2,0,36);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 6%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
    padding: 12px 20px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #fff;
}


.example li:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.example li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.example li:hover{
    background: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um position: absolute na classe .exemple e modificar a posição dela através do margin-left (sempre prefira margin-left.
O "rem" vai mudar a posição de acordo com o pai do elemento.
O absolute fará com que eleposicione pelo corpo html sem afetar outros elementos.
você pode modificar o valor do margin-left de acordo com o local que deseja colocar! inclusive pode colocar valores negativos.

```css
.example li{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -3rem;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    background: rgb(2,0,36);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 6%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
    padding: 12px 20px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #fff;
}
```